# Wicket's input looses behavior after the form it's in is submitted

Tags: forms, input, submit, wicket, behavior

I have a form and a series of panels containing inputs inside it, as a list. When I click the add button, the form is submitted and a new item is added into this form. Input inside a newly created panel gets date-picking behavior. The problem is that it cancels behavior applied to inputs which already were on that form (added previously). Inputs in other forms are not affected.

Each field behavior is applied onto has unique name. Values inside inputs are processed correctly.

How to preserve behavior applied on old inputs?

Comment: Please share your code. What you are saying should work normally so without code it is hard to say what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> How to preserve behavior applied on old inputs?

You probably put your input fields into a ListView, right? If so, try calling ListView.setReuseItems(true). This setting makes sure that when you add something to the listview and it is rendered again that the old items (with the old input fields and their behaviors) will be kept instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to be a case.